# Rails/Ruby: Get Last 4 Digits of Credit Card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know I've seen a few similar questions, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm sending a 16 digit number to my Credit Card controller, but I only want the last four. I've been trying every version of [-4..-1] to [14-16] to last(4) and I still get the same error: too many digits. This is the line of code I have right now (:last_4 is sent to controller with 16 digits) :

```
credit_card_params[:last_4 => credit_card_params[:last_4].last(4)]
```

The field is an integer field. Here is a sample input:

```
1234567890987654
```

And that should produce this:

```
7654
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I very much appreciate all of your responses. It u=turns out this is in fact a string. In any case, I've been pulling my hair out over this. Still doesn't work! This is my code, and my controller is still complaining that there's too many chars:

```
ccNum=credit_card_params[:last_4]
ccNum = ccNum[-4..-1] 
credit_card_params[:last_4 => ccNum]
@credit_card = CreditCard.new(credit_card_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @credit_card.save #HERE IS THE ERROR!
```

and this is the code in the form:

```
<%= f.label :last_4, "Credit Card Number" %><br>
<%= f.number_field :last_4 %>
```

leaves string 1234123412341235 unchanged, with this error message:

> 1234123412341235 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4

If anyone can figure this out I would really appreciate it.

Comment: show some more code please, like from where you are sending or where you are recieving ?

Comment: credit_card_params, is it a number or string?

Comment: Provide sample input, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: Did you use my solution?

Answer (score 5):

Consider this:

```
cc = 1111222233334444 # 16 digits in int
cc = cc.to_s # as a string now
cc = cc[-4..-1] # as a string "4444"
cc = cc.to_i #now as a int 4444
```

Or in just one line

```
cc = cc.to_s[-4..-1].to_i
```

Comment: Yep :) So this wouldn't even require to `to_s` ;)

Comment: The db I was assignmed to work with has ints for last_4. I tried this code and I got this: "syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '(' ...dit_card_params[:last_4].to_s.[-4..-1].to_i] ... ^ /workspace/eytan/app/controllers/credit_cards_controller.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting keyword_end ...d_params[:last_4].to_s.[-4..-1].to_i] ... ^"

Comment: after `.to_i` there shouldn't be a `]`. Try again carefully :)

Comment: @PatNowak than you very much for your persistence, unfortunately still not there. Please check updated question for more details.

Comment: You have there string instead of int? Yo should use `to_i` there. You can send link to your repo with this project as well.

Comment: Check out the updated question. All the code you need is there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
last_4 = credit_card_params[:last_4].to_s.last(4)

credit_card_params[:last_4] = last_4
```